# Visual Studio 2012 themes colors

Tags: visual-studio-2012, themes

I'm developer of plugin (extension) for Visual Studio. I use standard datagridview in my plugin. Datagridview uses standard defaultcellstyle

Everything is fine if using Light theme for VisualStudio. But text in cells is not visible in case of Dark scheme (until you select cell/cells)

What colors should I use for cell to serve Light and Dark themes?